# RStudio Server Initialization Error on Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, homebrew, r

I have installed RStudio Server using Homebrew on a Mac Pro Server with El Capitan. Then I followed instructions in the INSTALL file. When I launch RStudio Server from the host computer (http://localhost:8787) or remotely, it accepts my username and password but then I get this error:

"RStudio Initialization Error: Unable to connect to service".
This seems to be common with Linux installs, but none of those posted solutions solve the problem on my Mac. I tried logging in as different users and administrators but I the same error message either way.

Comment: Did you check `brew info rstudio-server`?

Answer (score -1):

Solved - there was an error in my .plist file

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions